# How can I instantiate Kendo PDFViewer?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, pdf-viewer

I can't use html helpers to instantiate a kendo pdf viewer. My company has a Telerik account. Error image and referenced telerik dll's below. Anything else I can check?

[Telerik references in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmcXO.png)
[pdfviewer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnJCA.png)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most probably caused by the usage of an old dll reference where the component is still not added or some cache issue with the Visual Studio. I would recommend to check again if you are using the latest version of Kendo dll or probably restart the Visual Studio.

If it is still not working the best apraoch is to connect with Telerik support through your company's account and share a dummy project where the issue could be reproduced.

Greetings,
Plamen